# Failed to download Chromium Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download

Tags: polymer

I am trying to install polymer-cli version 3 in my Windows and I am getting the error mentioned in this question. Searching around I reach that it is a problem with kind of PDF Generator from NPM dependencies. Sincerely, it doesn't make sense to me but I still try follow the recommendation mentioned in https://github.com/webpro/reveal-md/issues/191.

Bellow, the full error:

```
C:\dev\polymer2\sample>npm install -g polymer-cli@next --no-optional
C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\polymer -> C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\bin\poly
mer.js

> puppeteer@1.3.0 install C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\puppeteer
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to download Chromium r549031! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
{ Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND storage.googleapis.com storage.googleapis.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'storage.googleapis.com',
  host: 'storage.googleapis.com',
  port: 443 }
npm WARN rollback Rolling back debug@3.1.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '
C:\Users\my-user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\puppeteer\node_modules\https-proxy-agent\nod
e_modules'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.3 (node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any
"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: puppeteer@1.3.0 (node_modules\polymer-cli\node_modules\puppeteer):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: puppeteer@1.3.0 install: `node install.js`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

+ polymer-cli@1.7.0-pre.17
updated 1 package in 15.762s

C:\dev\polymer2\sample>polymer --version
1.7.0-pre.17
```